# How to add loading indicator to AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I would like to show loading indicator in AutoCompleteTextView while loading data from web-service. Preferably it should be shown on right side of autocomplete (f.i. animation like in progress control - spinning wheel). How this can be done?

Answer (score 7):

> I would like to show loading indicator in AutoCompleteTextView while
>   loading data from web-service.

Put a `ProgressBar` with an indeterminate look on the right of the widget and extend the `AutoCompleTextView` class like this:

```
public class AutoCompleteLoadding extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

    public void setLoadingIndicator(ProgressBar view) {
        mLoadingIndicator = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
        // the AutoCompleteTextview is about to start the filtering so show
        // the ProgressPager
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.performFiltering(text, keyCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
        // the AutoCompleteTextView has done its job and it's about to show
        // the drop down so close/hide the ProgreeBar
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onFilterComplete(count);
    }

}
```

Pass the reference to the `ProgressBar` with the `setLoadingIndicator()` method. This assumes that you're making the web service requests in the adapter(of the `AutoCompleteTextView`)/the adapter's filter.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use progress bars not spinners. Use the graphical view to lay them over your AutoCompleteTextView fields and set their id. I set mine to progressLoading.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressLoading"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewId"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewId"
    android:paddingTop="14dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip" />
```

Then in your activity/fragment:

```
final ProgressBar barProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressLoading);
originProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It is automatically visible so we initially set it to hidden. We then set it to VISIBLE on your addTextChangedListener on the AutoCompleteTextView. Then whenever that tasks completes you set it back to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

To add a progress bar within an AutoCompleteView, you can easily do the following :

First create a Custom AutoComplete class like so:

```
public class AutoCompleteWithLoading extends AutoCompleteTextView{
    private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;


    public AutoCompleteWithLoading(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AutoCompleteWithLoading(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoCompleteWithLoading(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public AutoCompleteWithLoading(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public AutoCompleteWithLoading(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes, Resources.Theme popupTheme) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes, popupTheme);
    }


    public void setLoadingIndicator(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        mLoadingIndicator = progressBar;
    }

    public void dispayIndicator(){
        if(mLoadingIndicator != null){
            mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        this.setText("");
    }

    public void removeIndicator(){
        if(mLoadingIndicator != null){
            mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards, Add this to your XML

```
         <thriviastudios.com.views.view.AutoCompleteWithLoading
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/NotPresentationText"
                android:id="@+id/activity_activities_search_city_text_view"
                android:popupBackground="@color/app_bg"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/app_bg_darker"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="City"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                />


                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </FrameLayout>
```

NB: Use the full path to your Custom AutomComplete class

Then, in your Activity or fragment, you get a reference to the indicator as well as the AutoComplete. Attach the progress bar to Autocomplete like so:

```
city.setLoadingIndicator(indicator);
```

and you can further show or remove the indicator when desired like so:

```
city.dispayIndicator();
```

and

```
city.removeIndicator();
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the following elements within a ContraintLayout:

- Add a AutoCompleteTextView
- Add a vertical guideline in your constraint layout to align the progress bar.
- Add a progress bar

Here's an example:

```
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/searchFormKeyword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/Assignment9Green"
                android:hint="Enter the Keyword"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/Assignment9HintGrey"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </AutoCompleteTextView>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/Assignment9Green"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]